# Android Studio - What is the Java Resources Folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-resources

I know there are two well-known folders where one can put resources.

The first is the `/assets` folder, the documentation says:

> Contains file that should be compiled into an .apk file as-is. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.

The second is the `/res` folder, the documentation says:

> Contains application resources, such as drawable files, layout files, and UI string. See Application Resources for more information.

Now i was wondering, there is a third option to create a resource folder `"New > Folder > Java Resources Folder"`
To me i looks like some part of the Android Plugin in IntelliJ because it has a little Android symbol in front of it [image].

Any ideas what the use of it could be? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

My first guess would be to use it in situations where you want to supply resources to a JVM Test.

Comment: I also could not find any documentation on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In standard java world

  Resources can be embedded directly in "your source tree" and used with Class's method getResource (see java documentation for a more precise description).
- In android world

  This practice is not recommanded (do not work at all, because such resources are removed from generated APK). You can still declare Java resources folders (see build.gradle :
  `sourceSets {
      main {
          resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java/yourresourcesfolder']
      }
  }`
  [image: Android studio Java Resources folder]
  And the result in the apk :
  [image: Generated apk]
- Conclusion

  As resources's folder tree is removed,using java's resource folder become from my point of view, useless (in an android projet). Using android's asset folder is a better choice (also avoid resource's name conflict, but it's an another story :D )

Comment: So the option is not part of the Android Plugin. It just has a misleading icon

Comment: Max, I've added my answer below with an use case where it's used in an Android App.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, but I want to bring an answer that explain one use case for the java resources directory on Android. If this folder exists in the options of a project it's because something can be done with it...

Enters the [Service Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ServiceLoader), that helps to connect other services (aka libraries) into your main app, it can be used as a [Gateway](https://martinfowler.com/articles/gateway-pattern.html) for your Android library to extend the functionality of a feature, exposing only the interfaces or abstract classes, with the Service Loader providing the implementation instead of your project having direct access to them.

Here is an [example of how it's implemented](https://dzone.com/articles/play-with-java-serviceloader-forget-about-dependen). So, in summary the folder (META-INF/services) and files you have to create in order to use the Service Loader on an Android App, NEED to be inside this `Java Resources Folder`, otherwise your provider won't be able to see any implementation.

You can see it working in my sample here if you want to check it out: https://github.com/difereto-globant/test-library-feature/tree/1.0.9.